# Add Electron API method types to window element for typechecking in Svelte

Tags: typescript, electron, svelte

I use `ipcMain` to make API calls from Svelte. Normally, I would do something like this:

```
const get_version = async () => {
    version = await window.api.GetVersion();
}
```

Which gets handled like so:

```
//preload.ts
const WINDOW_API = {
    GetVersion: () => ipcRenderer.invoke("get/version")
}
contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld("api", WINDOW_API);
```

```js
//main.ts
ipcMain.handleOnce("get/version", () => app.getVersion());
```

Although this code works fine, Typescript gives this error:

> Property 'api' does not exist on type 'Window & typeof globalThis'.ts(2339)

The error shows up in `.svelte` files. I tried to fix this by making an interface in my `global.d.ts` file like so:

```
//global.d.ts
interface Window {
    api: any;                                   //attempt 1
    api: { GetVersion: () => Promise<string>; } //attempt 2
}
```

But both attempts failed and the error persists. I know that I can use something like `(window as any)` to suppress this error, but as my API calls grow I believe typechecking will be very helpful and so I want to try to solve this problem.

How can I solve this?

---

Note 1: I am fairly certain I have set up Typescript typechecking correctly for Svelte files, as I am already using custom types.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out I had to move the interface to global declaration for it to be picked up by Svelte. After modifying my global declaration typescript like shown below, the problem was solved.

```
declare global {
    interface Window
    {
        api: any;
    }
    //...
}
```

However, the weird type persists. Normally, `window` should be of type `Window` but instead it is `Window & typeof globalThis`. I have still not figured out why this is and I am interested in learning what exactly causes this.